# How to get table and schema name for entity in JPA 3 / Hibernate 6?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to create native SQL queries so I need to know entity table and schema name. I found two solutions in internet, but they are not supported in Hibernate 6:

```
#1
var session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.getDescriptor(Person.class).getDefaultTable().getTableQualifier(); <-- getDescriptor() not found

#2
EntityType<Person> entity = manager.getMetamodel().entity(Person.class);
EntityTypeImpl entityTypeImpl = (EntityTypeImpl) entity;        
ClassDescriptor descriptor =  entityTypeImpl.getDescriptor();<-- getDescriptor() not found
String schema = descriptor.getDefaultTable().getTableQualifier();
```

Could anyone say how to do it in Hibernate 6 or JPA 3?